# python playwright i want control the same browser,when i use playwright develop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I have come across a special website where I can only log in to one browser at a time, other people cannot log in again with the username and password。
So I need playwright to use the same browser as me, and can't clear cookies, if the cookies are lost, I can't log in to the website for development within 2 hours

I was using selenium before, I like the following parameters in selenium

```
# google start 
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=888 --user-data-dir="H:\selenium"

# selenium connect chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:8888")
```

I have spent 3 days searching the playwright official website and google, but I can't find any relevant

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
playwright=sync_playwright().start()
chromium=playwright.chromium.connect_over_cdp('http:127.0.0.1:8888')
context=chromium.new_context(accept_downloads=True)
page=context.new_page()
page.goto('https://passport.meituan.com/account/unitivelogin')
```

This shortcode still doesn't meet my needs